# Awk scripting help - Logic Issue

Tags: scripting, awk, logic

I'm currently writing a simple .sh script to parse an Exim log file for strings matching " o' ". Currently, when viewing output.txt, all that is there is a 0 printed on every line(606 lines). I'm guessing my logic is wrong, as awk does not throw any errors.

Here is my code(updated for concatenation and counter issues). Edit: I've adopted some new code from dmckee's answer that I'm now working with over the old code in favor of simplicity.

```
awk '/o'\''/ {
         line = "> ";
         for(i = 20; i <= 33; i++) {
           line = line " " $i;
         }
         print line;
    }' /var/log/exim/main.log > output.txt
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: For clarity's sake, I'm grepping for "o'" in email addresses, because ' is an illegal character in email addresses(and in our databases, appears only with o'-prefixed names).

EDIT 2: As per commentary request, here is a sanitized sample of some desired output:

```
[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] kathleen.o'toole@domain.com <kathleen.o'toole@domain.com> routing defer (-51): retry time not reached

[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] julie.o'brien@domain.com <julie.o'brien@domain.com> routing defer (-51): retry time not reached

[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] james.o'dell@domain.com <james.o'dell@domain.com> routing defer (-51): retry time not reached

[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] daniel_o'leary@domain.com <aniel_o'leary@domain.com> routing defer (-51): retry time not reached
```

The reason I'm starting at 20 in my loop is because everything before the 20th field is just standard log information that isn't needed for my purposes here. All I need is everything from the IP and beyond for this solution(the messages for each 550 error are different for each mail server in use out there. I'm compiling a list of common ones)

Comment: Do you have a single line from the original logfile?

Comment: I'll have to censor it(sensitive data there), but here is one:
2008-09-28 04:50:43 1KisKj-0000tX-L0 == james.o'stuff@domain.org <james.o'stuff@domain.org> routing defer (-51): retry time not reached

Comment: If you provide a sanitized sample file (a couple of lines-worth) and desired output, I'll be you could get a dozen free perl, python and ruby solutions that were a lot simpler than this.

Comment: are you trying to get the 20-33 **characters** from each line that matches 'o'?

Comment: Ah, you're correct. I just realized the lines 20-33 concept carried over from a similar script I was writing, that was engineered towards errors with longer lines. I will try expanding its boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real need for the grep here. Let awk select the matching lines for you (and fixing your concatenation bug as per ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ):

```
awk '/o'\''/ {
             line = "> ";
             for(i = 20; i <= 33; i++) {
               line = line " " $i;
             }
             print line;
        }' /var/log/exim/main.log > output.txt
```

Of course, you end up needing some weird escaping if you do it at the promp like above. It is cleaner in a script...

---

Edit: On the first pass I missed the += problem...

Also assuming that the line you gave above is partial, as it has only 13ish fields (by default fields are white space delimited).

Comment: I tried this, and after clearing the output.txt file, I'm still just getting a bunch of 0's.

Comment: You're correct. See my last comment on the question for why. I've updated my code accordingly.

Comment: Yes! It works. All I had to do was widen the for loop after adopting your code. Using straight awk on the file rather than piping it through grep and other things is alot simpler. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`+` means numerical addition in awk. If you want to concatenate, just place the constants and/or expressions separated with spaces.

So, this

```
line += " " + $i
```

should become

```
line = line " " $i
```

EDIT: *Iff* exim log files (I am more into Postfix :) are separated by a single space, isn't the following more simple:

```
grep -F o\' /var/log/exim/main.log | cut -d\  -f20-33 >output.txt
```

?

Answer (score 1):

"'" is not illegal in local parts.  From [RFC2821](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt), section 4.1.2:

```
Local-part = Dot-string / Quoted-string

Dot-string = Atom *("." Atom)

Atom = 1*atext
```

2821 further references [RFC2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) for non-locally-defined elements, so:

```
atext           =       ALPHA / DIGIT / ; Any character except controls,
                        "!" / "#" /     ;  SP, and specials.
                        "$" / "%" /     ;  Used for atoms
                        "&" / "'" /
                        "*" / "+" /
                        "-" / "/" /
                        "=" / "?" /
                        "^" / "_" /
                        "`" / "{" /
                        "|" / "}" /
                        "~"
```

In other words, "'" is a perfectly legal unquoted characted to have in an email localpart.  Now, it may not be legal **at your site**, but that's not what you said.

Sorry for not staying directly on topic, but I wanted to correct your assertion.

Answer (score 1):

Off task, and simpler still: python.

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    if "'" in line:
        fields = line.split(' ')
        print "> ", ' '.join( fields[20:34] )
```